# input for array not scanned/missing

Tags: c, arrays, scanf

input : 
8
(2 5 6 9 10 2 7 4)
expected output :
(2 7 9 9 12 5 7 6)
real output : (2 7 9 9)

this is for my college assignment and my first time asking here.
I dont know why, but 10 not scanned, any help ?

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main ()
{
int a = 0, b = 0, c = 0, a_u[a], a_s[a];
printf("jumlah inputan : ");
scanf("%d", &a);

printf("\nmasukkan bilangan : ");

for(b = 0; b < a; b++) {
    scanf("%d", &a_u[b]);
}

printf ("\n");
for(b = 0; b < a; b++) {
    if (b % 3 == 0){
        a_s[b] = a_u[b];
    }
    else if (b % 3 == 1){
        a_s[b] = a_u[b] + 2;
    }
    else if (b % 3 == 2) {
        a_s[b] = a_u[b] + 3;
    }
}

for(b = 0; b < a; b++) {
    printf("%d ", a_s[b]);
}
}
```

Comment: You need to read the value of `a` *before* allocating the arrays `a_u` and `a_s` ! (In your code above these arrays have a size of 0 !)

Comment: you are right, thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an issue here:

```
int a = 0, b = 0, c = 0, a_u[a], a_s[a];
```

Your arrays `a_u` and `a_s` are variable length. Variable length arrays are not necessarily standard C (you probably need at least a C99 compiler to take advantage of that feature). But let's assume for now that your compiler does support it.

More importantly, you have used the value of `a`, which is 0, as the size of those arrays.

This means that *any* code accessing `a_u` or `a_s` will exhibit **undefined behavior**.

Comment: VLAs were introduced with C99 (although gcc had them somewhat before this).

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at your arrays. At line 4, the 2 arrays that you have defined, **a_u** and **a_s** would have **"0"** size which is not a smart thing to do. This would further cause an undefined behavior leading to varying in executions. I don't understand the point of such declaration.